# Unable to connect to VPN using domain credentials but can using local admin

Tags: vpn, domain

I have re-installed windows and added the machine back onto our domain. If i log in as local admin i can connect to VPN and access outlook etc. If i log into the machine using Domain credentials it wont connect the the VPN and outlook will not connect to the mail server either.

The VPN is part of a Windows Small Business Server and the client is the inbuilt Windows 10 VPN connection.

The domain credentials are correctly configured and work on another machine.

Can someone point me in the direction to fix this?

Comment: You need to clarify this more.  Where's the VPN server? How's the VPN server configured? Is it set up with LDAP/RADIUS authentication? What's the VPN client?

Comment: The VPN is configured as part of Small Business Server and I am using inbuilt windows 10 VPN client to connect. The client says verifying credential and then sits at "connecting to server"

Comment: When you logon as local admin and connect to the VPN, what credentials ate being used?

Answer (score 0):

I just got this working by creating the VPN connections using the local admin account and clicking allow other users to use this connection.  Then i could connect using the Domain credentials account.  I still dont understand the reason for this though.

Comment: You're skipping a lot of steps in your explanation, but the gist of it is, by clicking that option, you allow domain credentials to log in, otherwise, the only accounts available are the local accounts to the server where the VPN service is hosted.  This is all conjecture though, because you aren't very descriptive in your question or your answers.